# How to capture an order from PayPal in Python

Tags: python, paypal, kivy, paypal-rest-sdk

I've been trying to understand how exactly the capturing process of the PayPal SDK works. I'm currently working on a Python Kivy Mobile App with a PayPal Checkout option. I've been trying to make this example here to work: [https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-Python-SDK#capturing-an-order but](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-Python-SDK#capturing-an-order%C2%A0but) get this error when executed:

```
422
{'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate', 'Content-Length': '584', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Date': 'Thu, 04 Mar 2021 18:32:56 GMT', 'Paypal-Debug-Id': 'd092a377ca029'}
{"name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","details":[{"issue":"ORDER_NOT_APPROVED","description":"Payer has not yet approved the Order for payment. Please redirect the payer to the 'rel':'approve' url returned as part of the HATEOAS links within the Create Order call or provide a valid payment_source in the request."}],"message":"The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.","debug_id":"d092a377ca029","links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-ORDER_NOT_APPROVED","rel":"information_link","method":"GET"}]}
```

From what I understand this happens because I both try to create and capture the order at the same time. How could I make it that the capture only starts when the customer has approved so I would most likely not see this error message? Any help is appreciated!

.py

```
def PayPal(self):
    client_id = "ID"
    client_secret = "SECRET"

    environment = SandboxEnvironment(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
    client = PayPalHttpClient(environment)

    request = OrdersCreateRequest()
    request.prefer("return=representation")

    request.request_body({
        "application_context": {
            "return_url": ""},

        "intent": "CAPTURE",

        "purchase_units": [{
            "amount": {
                "currency_code": "CAD",
                "value": str(App.get_running_app().cart)
            }}]})

    try:
        response = client.execute(request)
        print("Order With Complete Payload:")
        print("Status Code:", response.status_code)
        print("Status:", response.result.status)
        print("Order ID:", response.result.id)
        print("Intent:", response.result.intent)
        print("Links:")
        for link in response.result.links:
            print('\t{}: {}\tCall Type: {}'.format(link.rel, link.href, link.method))
            print("Total Amount: {} {}".format(response.result.purchase_units[0].amount.currency_code,
                                               response.result.purchase_units[0].amount.value))
            order = response.result
            print(order)
    except IOError as ioe:
        print(ioe)
        if isinstance(ioe, HttpError):
            print(ioe.status_code)
    webbrowser.open("https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=" + response.result.id)

    # Capture order
    request = OrdersCaptureRequest(order_id= response.result.id)

    try:
        response = client.execute(request)
        order = response.result.id

    except IOError as ioe:
        if isinstance(ioe, HttpError):
            print(ioe.status_code)
            print(ioe.headers)
            print(ioe)
        else:
            print(ioe)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The capture should only be done after the customer goes through an approval flow (at PayPal) and returns to your app.  If you specify a `return_url` when you create the order, this can be set to a [deeplink](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Deep-Linking-with-iOS-and-Android) back to your app, which should be an intent that then calls the function that only then does the capture.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! I will look into it.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that the default action when redirecting to PayPal is "continue", meaning the last button at PayPal will say continue, and you are expected to show an order review page on return.  If you want to skip showing a review step and do the capture and show the capture result immediately, then you should set the user_action to 'PAY_NOW'